# Wordpress Media Library Issue does not upload an image

Tags: wordpress

after uploading an image in the media library it uploads but does not show thumbnail when I edit this image in media library it throws an error

> Image data does not exist. Please re-upload the image

Any Help?

Comment: Please check your chmod options

Comment: I have chmod 777 on the wp-content/uploads but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Is this all images or some images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. Doing `chmod -r 777` on `uploads` fixed it. The `-r` will make it recursive, changing the permissions to all your directories inside.